# How to get data using API?

Tags: r, api

I need to get data using API, but my code cannot open the connection. I would appreciate if you could let me know how to resole this error.

Code:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

Sp500 <- tq_index("SP500") %>% add_column(exchange = "SP500")
sp400 <- tq_index("SP400") %>% add_column(exchange = "SP400")
sp600 <- tq_index("SP600") %>% add_column(exchange = "SP600")
NASDAQ <-tq_exchange("NASDAQ") %>% add_column(exchange = "NASDAQ")
NYSE<-tq_exchange("NYSE")%>% add_column(exchange = "NYSE")
#Rus2000 <- tq_index("RUSSELL2000") %>% add_column(exchange = "RUSSELL2000")
#Rus1000 <- tq_index("RUSSELL1000") %>% add_column(exchange = "RUSSELL1000")
tickers <- rbind(NASDAQ,NYSE)

str(tickers)
```

Error:

```
> NASDAQ <-tq_exchange("NASDAQ") %>% add_column(exchange = "NASDAQ")
Getting data...

Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&exchange=nasdaq&download=true'
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(con, "rb") :
  URL 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&exchange=nasdaq&download=true': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
```

Comment: I get a successful run when I do `NASDAQ <-tq_exchange("NASDAQ") %>% add_column(exchange = "NASDAQ")`. Maybe the site is down??

Comment: Are you running behind a firewall? Whenever I have network issues with R code at work, it's usually because I haven't set the proxy. Eg. `Sys.setenv('ALL_PROXY'='http://proxy.company.com')`

Comment: @Marcus. I am using my own laptop. Besides, I do not have any proxy based on my settings->proxy.

Comment: @89_Simple based on [this issue](https://github.com/business-science/tidyquant/issues/226), there is a problem. How does it work for you?

Comment: @ebrahimi Hi! To be frank, I've never coded in `R`, but based on the error message I have a comment. Are you using any kind of VPN or something that bypasses tahriim? If not, you may want to do that.

Comment: @ebrahimi I also have to point out that you may want to check your network settings and restart it. It sometimes happens that windows based systems that do not work properly with APIs suffer from the mentioned problem.